# How to make my audit trail plugin work

Tags: grails, audit

I am in an need to use audit trail in my grails application i have tried all methods but audit log is empty is there any way to rectify it.I need to actually record operations such as insert,delete and update.

Below is what I followed:-

```
package audit 

class Person { 
    static auditable = true 
    String firstName 

    static constraints = { 
        firstName(nullable:true,size:0..60) 
    } 

    def onSave = { 
        println "new person inserted" 
    } 

    def onUpdate = { 
        println "person was updated" 
    } 

    def onDelete = { 
        println "person was deleted" 
    } 

    def onChange = { oldMap,newMap -> 
        println "Person was changed ..." 
        oldMap.each{ key, oldVal -> 
            if(oldVal != newMap[key]) { 
                println " * $key changed from $oldVal to " + newMap[key]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide some code and more information on the exact problem?

Comment: I have an application in grails in that i need to use audit trail.I have tried this code.I installed plugin and created a domain class Person and written methods to save. Now i can see table in database but no records in that.How to fire events to link with the database.

Comment: The code which i followed is package audit
class Person {
 static auditable = true
 String firstName static constraints = {
  firstName(nullable:true,size:0..60)
   }
 def onSave = {
  println "new person inserted"
 }
 def onUpdate = {
  println "person was updated"
 }
 def onDelete = {
  println "person was deleted"
 }
 def onChange = { oldMap,newMap ->
  println "Person was changed ..."
  oldMap.each({ key, oldVal ->
   if(oldVal != newMap[key]) {
    println " * $key changed from $oldVal to " + newMap[key]

Answer (score 0):

Other listservs that I check have suggested that the current audit-logging plugin is buggy, so you may just be experiencing a bug in the plugin.  Also, I believe it has been forked and is actively being rewritten (http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPAUDITLOGGING), so you may not want to spend too much time with it right now.

With that said, I scaffolded a simple application with the domain you provided and the plugin did write out the *println* statements, but it only recorded the updates correctly in the database to the `AUDIT_LOG` table.  The 2 inserts I attempted recorded `null` for both the `NEW_VALUE` and `PROPERTY_NAME`.

[image: Grails dbconsole window]